# Validar campo com valor inteiro, em formato decimal (verificar se valor é menor que)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá, minha questão é sobre uma validação de campo para valor decímal.  Se o valor for menor que 500,00 mostro uma mensagem de erro, senão passo para o segundo campo, assim que a pessoa digita o valor já vai adicionando a máscara.

Estou usando desta maneira:

```
function valid_simulation(form1) {

if(parseInt($("#selector").val()) < 500) {
alert("valor não é valido");
    return false;
}

}
```

Dessa forma consigo validar um valor inferior a 500,00, mas se for superior a 1.000,00 ele mostra a mensagem de erro.

Comment: seu campo tem máscara? se sim, o problema pode ser o `.`

Comment: Bem-vindo, leia esse post https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Colocando `parseFloat` no lugar de `parseInt` já não resolve?

Comment: Laércio, não resolve, valeu.

Comment: rLinhares, sim tem máscara... se tiro o ponto ai valida, mas preciso do ponto. tenho que encontrar uma forma de adicionar o ponto e validar. Valeu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O erro está acontecendo pois em linguagem javascript os decimais são separados por `.` e não por `,`. Logo, se você "parsear" uma string que contém um ponto para int, o número se torna um inteiro diferente, pois neste caso ele ignora a vírgula:

```
parseInt("1.000,00"); //mostra 1
parseInt("10.000,00"); //mostra 10
parseInt("100.000,00"); //mostra 100
```

Você precisa retirar os pontos para realizar o parseInt de maneira correta.

```
parseInt("1.000,00".replace(".","")); // mostra 1000
parseInt("10.000,00".replace(".","")); // mostra 10000
parseInt("100.000,00".replace(".","")); // mostra 100000
```

No seu código:

```
function valid_simulation(form1) {

    if(parseInt($("#selector").val().toString().replace(".", "")) < 500) {
        alert("valor não é valido");
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Biio, perfeito funcionou. Obrigado!